# sqlite3 automatically exit after few minuate i started it

Tags: sqlite

i just download sqlite3 for windowns from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

but it didn't run with sqlite3.exe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFNjd.png)

so i use cmd to run sqlite3.exe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qyT8.png)

but it shutdown even i do anything
i tried to change timeout to 0

```
sqlite>.timeout 0
```

or run cmd as administrator, changing path of environment variable and there was no difference plz help me

Comment: Please be more precise about the elapsing time. Specify it in seconds please. Is it constant over several, say 10, attempts?

Comment: Are you aware of anything unusual in your environment? For one, I find your prompt config noteable...